# Find point on Circle on Android

Tags: android, graphics, geometry, point

Everything seemed so plain and simple until I had to actually program it.

**What I've got**

I uploaded an image to explain it better.

- I have a circle and I know

  - it's radius
  - center point coordinates
  - each button's initial coordinates (the red circles).

I want to be able, when I rotate the gray circle image, with 10 degrees, to calculate red buttons new coordinates (x1y1, x2y2).

This shouldn't be hard to achieve for someone who knows math, but I didn't manage to find a suitable solution. I've also searched around here and couldn't find a working solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

[image]

The working solution, as Felice stated below is:

-first take care of rotation angle, on each redraw simply increment it

```
   angle = angle+mainRotationAngle;

    float x =  (float) (center.X + Math.cos(angle*Math.PI / 180F) * radius 
    float y =  (float) (center.Y + Math.sin(angle*Math.PI / 180F) * radius

    button.setX(x);
    button.setY(y);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easyer if you keep with you the button initial *angles*, then modify the angle to produce the rotation. so in pseudocode:

```
newAngle = Angle+rot;
xbutton = center.x+cos(newAngle)*radius;
ybutton = center.y+sin(newAngle)*radius;
```

If you really just have the coordinates of the buttons, you can convert them to the angle by using the function `atan2`, in pseudocode:

```
buttonAngle = atan2(button.y-center.y,button.x-center.x);
```

Comment: You have made my day Felice. Thank you very much for your help. I've posted the working android code in the question post.

Comment: Actually after testing this a bit more the buttons go crazy. As I slide the circle around, after a while buttons aren't on the same line anymore. Debugging to see what's all about. Any ideas in the meanwhile ? In case I rotate the circle in the other direction (not clockwise) does the formula change ?

Comment: store one single angle and increment one single angle. assume the other is always +180, so you avoid rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

x1 = x + r sin 10

y1 = y + r cos 10

x2 = x - r sin 10

y2 = y - r cos 10

Comment: As I commented before I have problems with buttons not moving correctly. Could you explain please in which cases I get + and in which ones I get - on the formula. Thank you.