# Placing an image on a circle

Tags: android

I have a circle and I want to place an image on the circle.

I know the angle and the circle radius and I need to get x and y coordinates for placing the image.

The image have to be ON the circle and not IN.

Code :

```
private void placeImageOnCircle(ImageView circle, RelativeLayout imageToMove, int angle)
{ 
    int radius = circle.getWidth()/2;

    // get marginX and marginY...

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(marginX, marginY, 0, 0);
    imageToMove.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by ON instead of IN?

Comment: Yes, ON means on the circle border.

Comment: Why don't you just place the Image ON the circle and change its height and width so thst it doesn't look clumsy?

Comment: so, you want the images center to be somewhere at the circles border?

Comment: Yes @tritop ! Abhishek Soni I don't really understand your answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the x and y of your circle and you know the radius. So you know that at 3 o'clock its x+radius, and at 12 o'clock its y+radius.

However, to get other points you will need some math.

x = radius * cos(angle) + xCenter;
y = radius * sin(angle) + yCenter;

The angle has to be in radians. So what you might do is

```
x = radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) + xCenter
y = radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) + yCenter
```

Also se other SO questions about it, like
 - [Find point on Circle on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789232/find-point-on-circle-on-android)
 - [Calculate points around a circle in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857735/calculate-points-around-a-circle-in-android)
 - [Getting Coordinates of a Point in a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818359/getting-coordinates-of-a-point-in-a-circle)

Comment: perhaps subtract xCenter, not add it?

Comment: Are you sure about that? I am not too good with formulas and its hot today, but I think I get the right numbers when testing it with +. Please tell me if its wrong and you are sure so I can edit the answer.